# Failed Start etcd

Tags: openshift, centos7, etcd

i install openshift origin in centOS7

i install ansible, but etcd cannot start, i did restart host, enable restart stop etcd (systemctl), but didnt work, please some one help me

> ```
> [root@master ~]# systemctl status etcd
> etcd.service - Etcd Server
> Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/etcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
> Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Sun 2019-06-23 12:37:06 EDT; 3min 7s ago
> Process: 20960 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c GOMAXPROCS=$(nproc) /usr/bin/etcd --name="${ETCD_NAME}" --data-dir="${ETCD_DATA_DIR}" --listen-client-urls="${ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS}" (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
> Main PID: 20960 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Jun 23 12:37:06 master.openshift.example.com systemd[1]: etcd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
> Jun 23 12:37:06 master.openshift.example.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Etcd Server.
> Jun 23 12:37:06 master.openshift.example.com systemd[1]: Unit etcd.service entered failed state.
> Jun 23 12:37:06 master.openshift.example.com systemd[1]: etcd.service failed.
> Jun 23 12:37:06 master.openshift.example.com systemd[1]: etcd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
> Jun 23 12:37:06 master.openshift.example.com systemd[1]: Stopped Etcd Server.
> Jun 23 12:37:06 master.openshift.example.com systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for etcd.service
> Jun 23 12:37:06 master.openshift.example.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Etcd Server.
> Jun 23 12:37:06 master.openshift.example.com systemd[1]: Unit etcd.service entered failed state.
> Jun 23 12:37:06 master.openshift.example.com systemd[1]: etcd.service failed.
> ```

how to running etcd.service

Comment: can you start etcd manually? - also do you know where is the log files is? check ls -al /var/log/etcd* - get the log and paste it here

Comment: did u try execute below command manually? may be the outputs may help you.
   /usr/bin/etcd --name="${ETCD_NAME}" --data-dir="${ETCD_DATA_DIR}" --listen-client-urls="${ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS}"

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, try removing etcd and re-installing. Refer to the respective product documentation to remove or add.